# Adding a PDF field in Landscape document in c#

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I am using PDF Clown for this purpose.

I wanted to add fields in PDF document. Actually I have successfully added fields in portrait PDF documents but doing the same in Landscape PDF documents is troubling.

Controls are placed vertically instead of horizontally.

Please help in this matter even if your proposed solution is using any other library. I will be very thankful.

Regards,

Mujtaba Panjwani

PS. I have tried PDFSharp.NET but that seems to have no support for creating fields and for iTextsharp, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTextSharp should do the trick. Have a look at the many examples available on their website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I just tried creating the field using iText but that still didn't resolve the problem. However now the rectangle is created correctly i.e. horizontally but still acrobat allows me enter text vertically. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: Just edited the above reply. Comment area isn't allowing me to press "enter"

Comment: You should edit your question and post the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes, it did the trick however I was concerned about its license for my client. Also adding checkbox using iTextSharp was little more trickier as I didn't find any good example for this but I managed it. thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your concern about the license? Since version 5, iText(Sharp) is under AGPL, meaning the code using it must be AGPL compliant. You also have the possibility to purchase a license that will drop this requirement.